# Bootstrap 4.4.1 no matter what I try, the select, text and textarea elements will not size as I need them to. Has anyone seen this before?

Tags: bootstrap-4, form-control

Bootstrap 4.4.1 has thrown me for a loop. I've got a decent layout, testing localhost, but no matter what I try the sizing I'm applying to my selects and textarea form elements are not working. Chrome, Firefox, IE11, and even Edge are overriding the size for a max width of no more than 280px.

I've applied the form-control class to each of the form elements, but that actually seems to further restrict my styling options.

Has anyone seen issues like this before? How did you resolve them?

Comment: Please, share some code that we can reproduce, so we can better help you.

Comment: [Inline forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms) is a commonly used solution. Another one is to use wrappers and apply the `max-width` to the wrapper element.

Comment: There is an example using a `<form class="inline-form">` ***and*** a wrapper (`<div class="form-group">`) at the same link, further down the page, just above [Disabled forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#disabled-forms).

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be very easy, Visual Studio snuck in a style.css file that included the following CSS statement. Once I removed that CSS file it worked as expected. Thanks to [Azametzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8598108/azametzin) and [tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/tao) for your patient response to my initial questions.

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```